# Who wrote The Urantia Book?

Tags: apocryphal-works, the-urantia-book

According to the [Wikipedia page about *The Urantia Book*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Urantia_Book), the author is unknown. On the [website](http://truthbook.com/urantia-book/the-authors-of-the-urantia-book) it's said the authors include universe beings (such as archangels, chief of Seraphim, etc.)

However somebody had to write the book. Is there any evidence pointing to who did it?

Comment: We don't really know who wrote this fake spiritual book. A quick read of Wikipedia shows authorship may not be really confirmed 100%, and I'm not sure how close we can get to finding out, but I'll see if any high quality answers with goof references pop up.

Answer (score 4):

### William S. Sadler (probably).

The book was likely authored (or part-authored) by a doctor named William Sadler, a man who garnered some local fame as a debunker of psychics but latterly formed his own religious cult and became immensely wealthy as a result.

He supposedly spent some time with an unconscious psychic who translated readings from various celestial beings to a court-trained stenographer. Sadler was suspiciously vague as to the identity of this remarkable individual (and the stenographer whose identity he had no reason to conceal) and hence it seems more likely that he wrote the pages himself, noting that he ready access to the various religious books and essays from which the papers were cribbed and was a prolific writer of books of medicine.

> Sadler confessed there that he'd been introduced to an individual in the summer of 1911 who was an apparent exception to his thesis, and that he had been present at two-hundred-fifty night sessions recorded by a stenographer: "This man is utterly unconscious, wholly oblivious to what takes place, and, unless told about it subsequently, never knows that he has been used as a sort of clearing house for the coming and going of alleged extra-planetary personalities." The doctor reassured his readers that the message being received was "essentially Christian and is, on the whole, entirely harmonious with the known scientific facts and truths of this age."
>
> <sub><sup>[Godtalk: Brad Gooch - Sleuthing the Urantia Book](https://www.randomhouse.com/knopf/authors/gooch/excerpt.html)</sup></sub>

In later years his story changed, having the psychic produce papers out of thin air which would arrive at his bedside table. Rather than handing over the original papers, Sadler would read them aloud and the members of the cult would take notes which would then be retyped as pages that eventually made up the bulk of the Urantia book.

Answer (score -3):

***THE URANTIA PAPERS*** or ***THE URANTIA BOOK*** (Urantia being our world’s name) is a valid, legitimate, and authentic divine revelation; it’s what it claims to be: the fifth epochal divine revelation, of five in total so far (the third and fourth epochal divine revelations being **The Bible** and **JESUS**, respectively, according to *URANTIA* itself).

For more information about *URANTIA*'s origin and authorship, read the main two (human) books about it (in this order):

1. https://ubannotated.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/MoyerBirthRev.pdf
2. https://www.scribd.com/document/278947513/A-History-of-the-Urantia-Papers

About its authorship: the invisible celestial revelators are listed at the end of each Paper (or chapter) authored by each celestial being associated to this divine revelation; and their nature are also described throughout the *URANTIA* Revelation; but of course not all of the universe’s celestial and other beings are its authors, nor are all universe beings revealed, therein.

Comment: Welcome to Literature.SE! This question focuses more on who wrote it, than what is it. In addition, it's frowned upon to just link to the sources - what if that site goes down? It would probably be best if you could rephrase your answer to answer the question a bit more directly, and maybe list some of the revelators described in the book itself.

Comment: The claim "valid, legitimate, and authentic divine revelation" assumes the existence of a divinity that makes revelations. Please add the following to your answer (a) evidence for the existence of a divinity and (b) evidence that this divinity occasionally uses books to communicate with people on Earth. Ideally, it would also be good to provide an explanation why this divinity would communicate with humans in a way that does not incontrovertibly prove its existence.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).